# Parse csv file in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv, meteor

How can I import and interpret csv files in Meteor?

I have a simple csv file

```
name, address, age, (...)
==================
A, A, 41, (...)
B, A, 41, (...)
C, A, 41, (...)
D, A, 41, (...)
E, A, 41, (...)
F, A, 41, (...)
(...)
```

and I just want to loop through each row and insert some docs in some collections depending on the values in the different columns in each row.

I guess I can do something like

```
var filename = "my_file.csv";
var csvFile = csv.readFile(filename);

for (var row in csvFile) {
    if (row[0] === "D") {
        Collection.insert(...);
    } else if (row[1] === "E") {
        ...
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to parse the file when using Meteor/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a CSV library like 
[Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/)

Comment: I have tried Papa Parse both by using https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse and https://github.com/harrisonhunter/papa-parse-meteor/ but I cannot make it work

Comment: What exactly is not working? I use Papa Parse in my application and have not had any problems.

Comment: In Meteor? Have you used `meteorhacks:npm` and `var Papa = Meteor.npmRequire("Papa")` to load it? I have tried many things and everytime it says that `Papa` is undefined. I have tried their simple examples such as `Papa.parse(file, { complete: function(results) { console.log("Finished:", results.data); } });`. How are you using the library?